# How delete keyboard layout in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard

If i add keyboard layout:

```
import win32api    
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", 1)
```

How can i delete it? There are no win32api.UnloadKeyboardLayout...

P.S. I have not english keyboard layout, but when i run some programms it automatically adds and i have english and japanese layout.Japanese layout contains english...so i need to write script for delete english layout.

P.S.2 I solved the problem. Just use ctypes

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('User32.dll')
UnloadKeyboarLayout = lib['UnloadKeyboardLayout']
UnloadKeyboarLayout(67699721) #for US English
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load a different one. Certainly you wouldn't want to have no layout at all. Or more correctly, collect which one they're using, change it to yours, then when they're done with your program, change it back to their preferred one.